# Change of Coordinate Matrix Collary Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb F)$, and let $\gamma$ be the basis for $\Bbb F^n$.
>   Show that if $[L_A]_γ=Q^{-1}AQ$, then the j-th column of Q is the j-th vector in $γ$.

I start by applying the theorem:
$[L_A]_γ = Q^{-1}[L_A]_{α} Q$

And let $[L_A]_α=A$, $α$ is another unknown basis of $\Bbb F^n$.

Then we have $Q=[I_n]_{γ→α}$, $Q$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

But I still can't figure out why the $j$-th column of $Q$ is the same as the $j$-th vector in $γ$.

Hope someone can give me some hints.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The statement is not correct as stated: if $[L_A]_{\gamma} = Q^{-1}AQ$, then there are many matrices that $Q$ could be.  For instance: for any such matrix $Q$ and non-zero $k \in \Bbb F$, $kQ$ will satisfy $(kQ)^{-1}A(kQ) = [L_A]_{\gamma}$.  I suspect that you are meant to prove the converse, that is: if $Q$ is the matrix whose columns are the elements of $\gamma$, then $[L_A]_\gamma = Q^{-1}AQ$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I've revisited the original question and found that you're right. English is not my first language, so sometimes it's hard for me to conveyed the question properly. I'll try considering $\alpha$ as standard basis!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\alpha$ denote the standard basis (that is, $e_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)$ is the first vector, $e_2 = (0,1,0,\dots,0)$ is the second, and so on).  Then if we take $Q$ to be the matrix whose $i$th column is the $i$th vector in $\gamma$, we have
$$
Q = [I_n]_{\gamma \to \alpha}
$$
We can that this is the case as follows: if $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are the elements of $\gamma$, then we note that the $i$th column of $[I_n]_{\gamma \to \alpha}$ is given by
$$
[I_n]_{\gamma \to \alpha} e_i = 
[I_n]_{\gamma \to \alpha} [v_i]_{\gamma} = [I_n v_i]_{\alpha} = [v_i]_{\alpha} = v_i
$$